# How to allow double and single quotes in a string that gets passed to an HTML value attribute?

Tags: html, string, vb.net

I have this HTML input that is supposed to allow double and single quotes in the value attribute.

```
<td><input id="Title" name="Title" class="required" value="$Title$" maxlength="50"/></td>
```

It gets replaced by this vb.net code:

```
Dim view As New
  StringBuilder(Utils.ReadView("someView.htm"))
        With view
            .Replace("$Title$", EscapeQuote(model.Widget.Title))
```

I've been trying to write EscapeQuote to replace all instances of double quotes, with the HTML equivalent & quot;

```
    Private Function EscapeDoubleQuotes(ByVal str As String) As String
        str = str.Replace("""", "&quot;")
        'str = str.Replace(Chr(34), "&quot;")
        'str = "'" & str & "'"
        Return str
    End Function
```

I have also tried using Chr(34) and encasing the entire string in single quotes. My working test case has been a string like "some string".
So in HTML, value=""some string"", which is an empty string, the input box is left blank.

I've also tried single quotes on the HTML attribute.

```
value='$Title$'
```

This allows strings enclose in double quotes, but obviously not string enclosed in single quotes.

My head spinning in double quote hell. Any other suggestions I haven't tried?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to encode quotes yourself you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method. It will take care of quotes and all other possible characters invalid in HTML. Example of usage:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()

        Console.Write(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("""Hello"""))

    End Sub
End Module
```

See it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7fVVh0